# Shrink only 1 item in flexbox

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am doing a navigation bar with a Logo, Search box, Login/Signup, and Cart wrapped in a flexbox. From here I want to reduce only the search box width as I am resizing my windows size.

Here is my css

```
.search{
  padding: .6em;
  @include flex(1 2 60%);
  //width: 60%;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  input{
    @include border-radius(6px);
    @include box-shadow(0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25));
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.logo{
  @include flex(1 0 20%);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.login{
  @include flex(1 0 10%);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  a{
    padding: 1.5em 1em;
  }
}

.cart {
  @include flex(1 0 10%);
  width: 10%;
}
```

I don't quite understand what does flex property do (flex grow, flex-shrink, flex basis) and I am not sure if it can help me on my problem. I read every explanation about it but I still cannot understand. Any help would be so much appreciated. TIA

Comment: Can you paste the HTML  and the sass/scss mixins ?
Or make an Codepen sample case to work with ! would be better